# I'm getting the below error while trying to connect from client host

Tags: openldap

I'm getting output when I do ldapsearch, but not able to connect/login to the LDAP user

ldapuser1@xx.xx.xx.xx's password:
Permission denied, please try again.

> ldap_start_tls: Connect error (-11)
>           additional info: TLS: hostname does not match CN in peer certificate SASL/GSS-SPNEGO authentication started
>   ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Local error (-2)
>           additional info: SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
>   (SPNEGO cannot find mechanisms to negotiate)

Comment: We need more information. Which client do you use, how do you try to connect? Show some code or parameters.

Comment: # base <dc=server,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: cn=ldapuser1
# requesting: ALL
# ldapuser1, People, server.com
dn: uid=ldapuser1,ou=People,dc=server,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: account
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
cn: ldapuser1
uid: ldapuser1
uidNumber: 10001
gidNumber: 101
homeDirectory: /home/ldapuser1
loginShell: /bin/bash
gecos: LDAP
userPassword:: xxxxxxxx
shadowLastChange: 17058
shadowMin: 0
shadowMax: 99999
shadowWarning: 7
# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success
# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1

Comment: I'm using SSL authentication method

Answer (score 0):

The relevant error, from your original paste:

> ldap_start_tls: Connect error (-11)
>   additional info: TLS: hostname does not match CN in peer certificate

As it says, the LDAP URI or hostname in your connection configuration does not match the CN (Common Name field) in the server's certificate. They have to match exactly.

If your client configuration is using a short hostname or an IP address, try changing it to use the server's fully-qualified name (including domain).